# How to write SVR's constraint from into a single function with loss function in linear case?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

[image: Constraint form]
[image: Unified form with loss function]

The loss function is an e-insensitive loss meaning won't punish anything smaller than a setting e. The slide simply says if choosing the right $\lambda$, the SVR is equivalent to solve the right one.

However, I can't figure out their detailed relation.

Comment: What is $\ell_c(\cdot,\cdot)$?

Comment: An e-insensitive loss meaning won't punish anything smaller than a setting e, namely, max (|y-w^t x_i -b| -e, 0).